# Unable to locate package sqlite3 in Dockerfile

Tags: python, linux, docker, sqlite

I am pretty new to building containers with Docker, I commonly use conda environments for my day to day work, however this time I needed to work with a computation server that only allows running docker containers. I want to build an image that will allow me to run my Pytorch code. What I prepared is like the following, a pretty common Dockerfile for deep learning applications:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:12.2.0-devel-ubuntu20.04

CMD ["bash"]

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 LC_ALL=C.UTF-8

ENV SHELL=/bin/bash

RUN apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends \
        git \
        wget \
        cmake \
        ninja-build \
        build-essential \
        python3 \
        python3-dev \
        python3-pip \
        python3-venv \
        python-is-python3 \
    && apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get clean -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 

RUN apt-get install sqlite3

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/python3/venv/base
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install jupyterlab

RUN python3 -m pip install pandas

RUN pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118

COPY entry_point.sh /entry_point.sh
RUN chmod +x /entry_point.sh

# Set entrypoint to bash
ENTRYPOINT ["/entry_point.sh"]
```

When building the container, I get the following error:

```
  E: Unable to locate package sqlite3
```

When I remove the sqlite3 installation line, the image builds and when I run the corresponding container and try to install sqlite again with the same command in CLI, I get the same error. I am using as the base image "nvidia/cuda:12.2.0-devel-ubuntu20.04" that is supposed to bring Ubuntu20.04 environment along with Cuda, however the apt package manager cannot seem to find a very common tool that is Sqlite. I also make an `apt-get update` call in the Dockerfile right in the beginning. I am not seeing what is missing here unfortunately. Should I use an another base container perhaps?

Comment: The previous `RUN` line deletes all of the local state used by APT.  Does it work better to move `sqlite3` inside the list of packages in the longer `RUN apt-get install` command?

Comment: Yes. it seems to work, an overlook on my part. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you Dockerfile, you

```bash
RUN apt-get update \
    && ...
    && apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get clean -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 
RUN apt-get install sqlite3
```

The end of the first `RUN` command cleans up all of APT's state, so when the second `RUN apt-get install` happens, it's forgotten that any packages exist.

In the first `RUN` command, you have a list of packages you install.  Add `sqlite3` into that list.

```bash
RUN apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends \
         ...
        python-is-python3 \
        sqlite3 \              # <-- move up into this list
    && apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get clean -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

An incremental rebuild will be slower, but if you (or your CI system) builds the image from scratch, it will be somewhat faster to only invoke the APT/dpkg machinery once.

If you do need it as a separate `RUN` line for whatever reason, you'll need to repeat the `apt-get update` inside the second `RUN` command.  Copying the overall structure of the first `RUN` command would make sense, just using a different package list.

Comment: This did not work for me. I am running a linux (debian) docker image on an M1 (arm64 or aarch64) Macintosh. I still get the error E: Unable to locate package sqlite3

Comment: The [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/sqlite3) does exist for arm64 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Indeed it does, @david-maze, for Ubuntu. Unfortunately I am running the official docker file python:3.11.7. Do you think, if I add this repo to the sources list I can `apt-get install` it without screwing everything else up? Any pointers on how to do that?

Comment: I think `python` is based on plain Debian and not Ubuntu, but a [Debian `sqlite3` package](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/sqlite3) exists too.  If combining the package installation into a single `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install` line doesn't work, you might ask a new question with the relevant Dockerfile and error message.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to use the Bookworm distro, `apt-get update && apt-get install sqlite3`, and that was about it. Everything just sort of worked from then on. Thanks for the pointers!